# How to get a button to perform a function when it has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button below:

```
<p><button id='submitstudents'>Submit Students</button></p>
```

What I want the button to do is to trigger the `editvalidation()` function and if that is passed then proceed with the confirmation. I have the jquery code set up for the validation and for showing the confirmation if the validation has passed but how do I get the button to return the `editvalidation()` whenc clicked on?

Below is relevant jquery code:

**editvalidation():**

```
        function editvalidation()
{
    if ($("#coursesDrop").val()==""){
        $("#courseAlert").html("Please Select a Course from the Course Drop Down Menu");
    }
    if ($("#coursesDrop").val()!="" && $("#courseadd").children().length==0){
        $("#courseAlert").html("You have not Selected any Students you wish to Add into Course");
    }
    if ($("#coursesDrop").val()!="" && $("#courseadd").children().length!=0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**showConfirm():**

```
         function showConfirm(){

          var courseNoInput = document.getElementById('currentCourse').value;
          var courseNameInput = document.getElementById('currentCourseName').value;

          if (editvalidation()) {

         var confirmMsg=confirm("Are you sure you want to add your selected Students to this Course:" + "\n" + "Course: " + courseNoInput + " - " + courseNameInput);

         if (confirmMsg==true)
         {
         submitform();   
     }
  }
}
```

**current even to check for click on button:**

```
 $('body').on('click', '#submitstudents', showConfirm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$('#submitstudents').on('click', function(){ if(editvalidation()) showConfirm(); });
```

?

Comment: Same outcome as other answer, nothing happens, no validation appears when incorrect, no confirmation appears when correct

Comment: @user2048994 is the submit button created in HTML, or in the DOM by some JavaScript? If it's the latter, you may need to use a slightly different syntax for `on`.

Comment: @duncI am simpl using a `button` html code to display the button but the functionality of the button is done in the DOM by some jquery as you mentioned

Comment: Here is a very (over)simplified version of what you are attempting to do.  http://jsfiddle.net/Czdfx/

Comment: @joe It is not letting me open the fiddle up correctly. It is just showing a image of a cup saing initalizing the awesome

Comment: @joe let me try and post m view source code inside a jsfiddle

Comment: @user2048994 Move your event binding into your $(document).ready() function and comment out the if(validation()).  I was able to get the confirm() message to show by doing this.

Comment: @Joe Can I ask how to get the messages from the validation to appear as that if you do not select a course and submit, then it should displaythe validation message, only when validation is passed whould it then display the confirmation

Comment: @user2048994 You had the wrong selector for the message container.  You were using #coursesAlert as opposed to #studentsAlert.  Another updated fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/PhWbm/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#submitstudents').click(function(){
  if(editvalidation())
    showConfirm();
});
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work, nothing happens when I click submit button and no errors are shown

Comment: Try throwing a console.log() or alert() inside of editvalidation() and see if it is even firing.

Comment: I previously put an alert inside both editvalidation and showconfirm and when I click on the button, it alerts the editvalidation alert when validation not met. When validation is met, it still deisplays alert for editvalidation, not showConfirm

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before. This code works perfect all the time:

```
$('#submitstudents').live('click', function(){
   ...do what ever you want...
});
```

Comment: Only use .live() in jQuery versions < 1.7.

Comment: I am using 1.7.2. Im guessing I am better of using .on then?

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is not on clicking the button. Try to debug it using firebug and see what comes up?